# Google Apps Script How to access script from spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, runtime-environment

I have written a Google Apps Script script using the Apps Script App in Google Suite. I also created a spreadsheet using the same account. I want to add a button to my spreadsheet that runs the script when I click it. I added an image, right clicked, hit three circles and selected the "Assign script" option.
**Problem:**
I can only assign scripts that appear under tools>script editor. I cannot assign the script that I previously wrote by opening the Apps Script app directly (in the same account). I can copy paste the whole thing into the spreadsheet's scripts, but then I have to maintain two versions.
**What I want**
I want to directly assign the script that I wrote earlier to the button.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue:

Only functions in the script bound to your spreadsheet can be assigned to a clickable image/drawing:

> You can also assign an Apps Script function to an image or drawing in Google Sheets, **so long as the script is [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scripts_containers) to the spreadsheet**.

#### Use libraries:

As a workaround, I'd suggest [creating a library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#creating_a_library) for your [standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) (so that the script's functions can be reused in other scripts) and call it on the script bound to your spreadsheet.

You can do it the following way:

- Visit the standalone script (project called `STANDALONE` in this example) where you have your desired function:

```
function standaloneFunction() {
  // Do some stuff
}
```

- Create a version of your script: see [Creating a version](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/versions#creating_a_version).
- Click `File > Project Properties` and copy the `Project key`: see [Sharing a library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#sharing_a_library).
- Visit the script bound to your spreadsheet.
- Include the library in your bound script by clicking `Resources > Libraries` and paste the previous `Project key` into the `Add a Library` text box: see [Gaining access to a library and including it in your project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#gaining_access_to_a_library_and_including_it_in_your_project).
- Choose the function `Identifier` and the script `Version`:

[image]

- You can now call the standalone function in your bound script, using the `Identifier`:

```
function boundFunction() {
  STANDALONE.standaloneFunction();
}
```

- And finally you can assign `boundFunction` to your clickable image.

#### Reference:

- [Clickable images and drawings in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets)
- [Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)